Linear Hall sensor output contains random voltage spikes
I am currently designing a circuit for a Hall effect keyboard. The design is heavily inspired by the one posted in https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/(review-request)-newbie-with-a-schematic-and-pcb-for-a-hall-effect-keyboard/. Below is a simplified circuit of a single linear Hall sensor:

The sensor is connected to a decoupling capacitor. Its output goes through an RC filter with a -3dB cutoff at ~338kHz. The multiplexer is also connected to two decoupling capacitors. The output of the multiplexer then goes through an active low pass filter with the same cutoff and finally goes into the ADC input pin of the MCU. The analog power supply comes from a 5V bus power supply converted to 3.3V and filtered through a ferrite bead.
The graph below shows the ADC reading:

Here, I have not performed any switching for the multiplexer so the value is coming directly from a single sensor. I varied the distance of the magnet from the sensor as seen in the graph. There are some random voltage spikes in the graph as I moved the magnet and at a specific distance, there seem to be a lot of spikes as shown in the graph above. If the magnet stays stationary, there are no spikes.
I am very new to circuit design and the ADC reading is the only monitoring tool I currently have as I do not own an oscilloscope myself. Any ideas what are the possible causes for the noise? What can I do to improve the reading?
Edit: Here is a code snippet of my ADC sampling that can reproduce the problem.
// After initializing peripherals
HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);

uint16_t adc_value;

// ADC interrupt callback
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef *hadc) {
    if (hadc == &hadc1) {
        // Read ADC value into a 16-bit integer
        adc_value = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);

        // Start a 10us timer
        HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim10);
    }
}

// Timer interrupt callback
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim) {
    if (htim == &htim10) {
        // Restart the ADC
        HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);
    }
}

Since the ADC value is 12 bits. It should fit inside a 16-bit integer so I think overflow might not be an issue here.
Edit 2: It seems that using a 32-bit integer to retrieve the ADC value solves the problem.

Could you add you ADC sampling code?

@HansmitmFlammenwerfer I have edited the post with my code snippet at the end.

Perhaps post the entirety of your code? As one answer suggests this may have to do with the way your code manipulates the ADC reading.

@InBedded16 I have found the cause of the problem to be using a 16-bit integer to store the ADC value instead of a 32-bit one.  The code snippet above was literally the entire code I used when I plotted the graph above.

I think there is something going on with the way you interpret digital values as voltages: -

Things seem to go wrong every ~255 mV and, this may coincide with some aspect of the digital number but, I can't be sure.

Thanks for your insight. It seems that after I change the variable that stores the ADC value to a 32-bit integer, the spikes are gone now. However, I am still confused as why this happens since the ADC value is 12 bits and should fit inside a 16-bit integer.

OK glad to help but now, I'm at my personal limit. Maybe your best option is raise a new post that specifically asks about why changing to a 32 bit integer works compared to 16 bit. This site thrives on questions so, it makes sense to raise a new post but no need to cover what you had in this post other than to leave a link to it. New posts attract new users.
